# Resize all divs to the size of the tallest div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div container class with a width of 15%. Inside these containers I have image, the image has a a width of 100%. The problem is that not  every image has the same ratio, so some container divs are longer then others which cause my layout to "crack".

Is there a way to resize all the divs to the size of the tallest div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your divs using javascript find the max width.  Then loop back through all the divs and set each width to the maxwidth that you found.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion let me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781031/use-jquery-css-to-find-the-tallest-of-all-elements and fixed it for me.

Comment: Although, there's a "bug" in that code. When you resize the browser that height of the elements stays the same. I've update the fiddle, maybe you can check it out quick? > http://jsfiddle.net/76Rsh/64/ I guess the resize function doesn't do much because all the elements are the same height.

Comment: Looks like the first stackoverflow post was a bit old. This topic is a bit fresher and has a responsive solution > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437476/equal-height-divs-or-li-in-rows-with-fluid-width-and-height-90-finished